# Eliminating extra separator lines for empty rows in UITableView in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiview, ios8

While removing the extra separator lines in the tableview using the code, I create an outlet for the tableview in my viewcontroller and then set the

```
self.tableview.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

While checking for class UIView, the default initializer has the frame argument,

```
class UIView : UIResponder, NSCoding, UIAppearance, NSObjectProtocol, UIAppearanceContainer, UIDynamicItem, UITraitEnvironment, UICoordinateSpace {

    class func layerClass() -> AnyClass // default is [CALayer class]. Used when creating the underlying layer for the view.
    init(frame: CGRect) // default initializer
    var userInteractionEnabled: Bool // default is YES. if set to NO, user events (touch, keys) are ignored and removed from the event queue.
    var tag: Int // default is 0
    var layer: CALayer { get } // returns view's layer. Will always return a non-nil value. view is layer's delegate
}
```

Using,

```
self.tableview.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
```

also works. When the default initializer is different in the UIView class (which does inherit from a lot of other classes), why does the first method work and not give an error? How are the two lines which remove the separators different(if they are), and which one is more efficient and should be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIView` inherits `init()` from `NSObject`, that why it's valid and doesn't give any error. Every class in *Cocoa(Touch)* that works with *Objective-C* inherits from this class (maybe except `NSProxy`). And it's clear that `UIView` has it's `frame` property default to `CGRectZero` that why it still does work.

I would say you always go with `init(frame:)` since it's *Designated Initializer* for `UIView`. And it gives a clearer intent to the reader. <del>By using `init()`, you can't be sure that all the properties will be more properly set than using `init(frame:)`.</del>

### Update

After having done some little experiment, I found out that `UIView.init()` calls `UIView.init(frame:)` by passing `CGRectZero`. So, I would say that both are **totally equivalent**. But, I would still suggest you use `init(frame:)` since it can express a clearer intent to the reader. But that's up to your style.

Here's the code:

```
@interface MyView : UIView

@end

@implementation MyView

- (instancetype)init; {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"%s | %@", __FUNCTION__, NSStringFromCGRect(frame));
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

And by calling `[[MyView alloc] init];` it prints:

```
-[MyView initWithFrame:] | {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
-[MyView init]
```

### Update

Here's the *Swift* version:

```
class MyView: UIView {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        println(__FUNCTION__)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        println("\(__FUNCTION__) | \(frame)")
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        println(__FUNCTION__)
    }
}
```

Then you just call `MyView()` somewhere in your code.

Comment: How can we write something similar to this experiment in Swift?

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift 4.0**
Just Add the following code in the delegate methods

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
}
```